# Why does wrapping a dictionary in a class allow it to be used by an ASMX WebMethod?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

As I understand it, it is not possible to pass a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` to an ASMX web service because `Dictionary` implements `IDictionary`. Attempting to do so results in not only the method throwing an exception when attempting to call it, but also throws an exception when attempting to go to the web service URL in a browser:

> The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

However, I have found that if I create a class that contains a Dictionary property, and pass that to the web service method as a parameter, it works fine.

```
Public Class DictWrapper
    Public Property oDic as Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class

<WebMethod()>
Public function ReadDic(oDictWrapper as DictWrapper) As Boolean
    Return oDictWrapper("SomeBoolean")
End Function
```

Why does this example work? I can call this WebMethod with AJAX, passing a varying number of keys and values in the wrapped dictionary, no problem. How is this any different than just having the dictionary as a parameter of the WebMethod?

Comment: I suspect that the statement inside your wrapper class is intended to be `Public Property oDic As Dictionary(Of String, String)`. I didn't change it in my edit in case I am mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad that was a typo. Corrected.